# Omit leading 0 in char and append

Tags: c, logic, overflow, bit-manipulation

Say I have these 8 bit chars:

```
01111111  00011100  01101111
```

I want to omit the leading 0 and append the bits from char before like so:

```
11111110  01110011  01111000
```

*note that the last char has been padded with zeros.

Any advice on how to do this would be much appreciated. cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shift the first char up 1:

```
num[0] << 1;
```

This will turn `01111111` into `11111110`.  Now you need to OR the LSB with the MSB of the next char.  To do that you need a shifted copy of the next char:

```
char copy = num[1] >> 7;
```

This would turn `01110011` into `00000000`, since it's high bit was 0.  You can now OR the two:

```
num[0] |= num[1];
```

Which will give you what you want.

To do this with a sequence, you would need to loop and increase the shifts at each iteration up to 8, then reset.

Note that as chux points out, you are best off using *unsigned* types for stuff like this.

Comment: Insure the variable type is not signed else you will likely get unsatisfactory results if the most significant bit is set.